# Robotask task import XML

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing

I am trying to convert an excel spreadsheet into a suitable Variables XML file.

```
Sample schema

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root>
      <var00000059 type="FOLDER">
        <name type="STRING"></name>
        <value type="STRING"></value>
      </var00000059>
      
    </Root>
```

I have exported an example from RoboTask and used that as a XML map (image attached)

[image: Excel error]

I.e. final import would be for 2 vars

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <{ID} type="FOLDER">
    <name type="STRING">Variable name goes here</name>
    <value type="STRING">Variable value goes here</value>
  </{ID}>

  <{ID} type="FOLDER">
    <name type="STRING">Variable name goes here</name>
    <value type="STRING">Variable value goes here</value>
  </{ID}>
  
</Root>
```

I have added a name field and ID for the folder level but still can't export.

Can someone please provide a template if possible.

ty

```
Disclaimer: I haven't been able to get help from official support channels for the automation program robotask. So am asking for help here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example here: https://robotask.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8977#p8977
It creates the XML you want.
Save the text of the task to a file and use menu Task->Import to import the task into RoboTask.
Also you can simply copy task text and paste it into the task list.